# Give user permissions to specific folder ONLY

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, permissions, ftp

I'm using Amazon Linux on EC2 and I just added the user using `sudo adduser john`.

How can I give the user specific permissions to only ONE folder and all the sub folders in it? For example, they only have access to: `/var/www/html` and everything in it. How can I do that?

Comment: What is it that you really want to achieve?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su], [unix.se], or [sf].

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a jailed user which will have access to that folder.
Please follow this steps in this tutorial.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-restricting-ssh-user-session-to-a-directory-chrooted-jail/

Answer (score 0):

The chown command allows you to change the user and/or group ownership of a given file, directory, or symbolic link.

In Linux, all files are associated with an owner and a group and assigned with permission access rights for the file owner, the group members, and others.

You can use

```
sudo chown -R john folder_name
```